# Mesh with soft-body physics not appearing in render?

Tags: rendering, soft-body, visibility

I have a scene with multiple objects keyframed from rigid body sims, but since I can't keyframe soft body sims I don't know how to render it properly.

In fact I don't know how to render it at all, the mesh won't appear in my render.

I have tried several solutions found on here already :

1. Baking the simulation
2. Checking the visibility status of that object
3. Checking the material

You can review my blend file, the object in question is the one called "Wire Straight". If someone could help me out here, I'm new to blender and kinda lost :) Ty

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have activated their *Shadow Catcher* option, it makes these objects invisible, if you don't want to use them as shadow catcher surfaces you need to disable this option.

If you're talking about the object called *Wire Straight*, at the beginning it is hidden behind the objects with *Shadow Catcher*, and later on it moves away because of its *Surface Deform* modifier.

[image]

Comment: This isn't the object I'm talking about, my bad, I will edit the question to clear that out. The object is the one called "Wire Straight".

Comment: It seems to be hidden behind the shadow catcher objects, it is rendered if you move these objects

Comment: Oh is it on your end ? frame 190 the object is not behind anything and still not rendered for me :(

Comment: at frame 190 it has moved away from the camera frame because of a Surface Deform modifier

Comment: Oh wow ok, it is still in camera field on my screen. Maybe it's bugged then.. Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: what does it give if you disable the Surface Deform modifier?

Comment: Ohhh ok yeah. I changed the order of modifiers, surface deform before subdiv and that fixed it. Wouldn't have thought of that, thank you !!